# Refresh the viewpager dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a wallpaper downloading app and in that I have 5 tabs.
I have a *Downloads* tab that I want to refresh whenever an image is downloaded from the internet, but the problem is my `ViewPager` first binds the data `onCreate` and then only refreshes after I re-open the app.
How can I refresh the `ImageView` in `ViewPager` when the download of Image is Finished?

Comment: you dont refresh the Pager you refresh the Adapter with NotifyDataSetChanged()(

Comment: You can use some kind of event bus to prevent keeping references to views or fragments. The downloader would generate a message "download finished", and any view or fragment can react to that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use NotifyDataSetChanged() but you need to pass range 0 to total list element + downloaded items. So definitely work. Because it will not refresh all list it will refresh only list item in range and will update list with downloaded data.